# adding hook on course activity added

Tags: php, event-handling, hook, moodle, moodle-api

I need to be notified when a course activity (Assignment, Chat & Quiz) is added to a course.
I need to send a message to all enrolled users.

How can I add a hook on those events in moodle 2.9?

Thanks

Comment: It's not normal to change a course much after people have enrolled and started doing it. I think it will mess with your completions data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a `\core\event\course_module_created` event.

Use the example from this I answered recently, replacing `course_completed` with `course_module_created`:

[Email using cron and including attachment to email from moodle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010383/email-using-cron-and-including-attachment-to-email-from-moodle/35014226#35014226)